# Android: redesigning producer consumer /approach for sensor data

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have a single threaded Android application for reading data from beacons. I have a service that handles the beacon readings today (mainactivity just starts this service). I am noticing that my code base is becoming complex and need to be partitioned.

I want to have a producer thread that gets the data from the callback, from BLE Scan, and put into a queue that consumer thread (= existing service??) would handle. But I am confused on how this consumer thread has to look; because consumer thread (= existing service) also gets events from 1) GUI which is mainactivity and 2)several receivers that are defined in androidmanifest.xml.

So consumer thread cannot block on the queue and it some how has to handle events from GUI and receivers. How can I achieve this?

***EDIT***

It is a 24/7 app that always runs in the background and scans the beacons. Also, periodically pushes the data to AWS. Because we get callbacks at about every second, delivering them via Intent to the service is expensive (Intent = Thread creation and destruction). Because app has to process the scanned values and push data to AWS, we will be delaying/blocking callbacks from BLE scanning(from the logged timestamps, I notice I am getting callbacks at about once every 3 seconds because of the processing overhead in my code; while the same codebase without any processing is just scanning at about once every 500 ms). Hence I am thinking of multi threaded code producer and consumer model

Comment: BLE scanning 24/7 will be expensive in terms of battery, so you will either need to throttle scanning to only be periodically, or have a power source on your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

A single `IntentService` could process different messages in short-term threads, including:

1. Scan data
2. GUI event(s)
3. Other receivers

Each of these events would be passed to the service via an `Intent` with extras telling it which event to process and what data to use.  A thread would be started and live for as long as it takes to process each event.  The code in the thread would adjust the internal state of the service based on the passed data.

It's hard to say more without knowing exactly what you are trying to do, but an `IntentService` sounds like the closest construct to matching your use case.

Comment: If you are worried about tge CPU exoense of intents, you could replace the scan intents with insertion into a singleton processing queue,  Then only send an upload intent when the queue is full or enough time has passed since the last upload.

Comment: I need to process each callback in real time (or close to).